# global array gets overwritten

Tags: php, arrays, global

I guide my website's users through a 2 step selection with html select elements that are displayed one after the other. The first one is used to choose a trainer and the second one is used to choose a monster. After this one, I want to display a battle-screen with information on the trainer and the monster. Therefore I want to store the information in a global array. I tried to just use the POST array, but it gets overwritten once I include the battle-content.

On my little project I use a config.php file that is included via

```
require_once('config.php');
```

It also includes my functions.php. In this config file I declare an array like this:

```
$wahl = array('trainer' => 'test', 'monster' => 'test' );
```

Now in a function I write something to a new index of this array:

```
function trainernameBelegen($t) {
 global $con;
 global $wahl;
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `trainer` WHERE t_id = '".$t."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $wahl['trainer'] = $row['name'];

 echo $wahl['trainer'];
 }
```

This is executed after the first selection and works fine. I tested echoing the array and I got the value I expected.

**After the second selection though, the array get's overwritten and shows "test" and "test" again.**

This is the content part of the index.php

```
<?php require_once( 'config.php');
if (isset($_POST['s_tselect'])) {trainernameBelegen($_POST['trainerwahl']);}
if (!isset($_POST['monsterauswahl'])) {require_once('startseite.php');}
  else {require_once('battle.php');}
?>
```

It first requires the config.php, then checks if the trainer has been selected and if so calls the function that put's the trainer's name into the global array. If no monster has been chosen, startseite.php (with those selectors) is shown - else the battle screen.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: when does this "second selection" occur? remember that every http request is an INDEPENDENT php execution run, and results from one run will not be visible in the second+ runs, unless you've taken steps to preserve things.

Comment: in config file declare it like `global $wahl; $wahl = array('trainer' => 'test', 'monster' => 'test' );` and check

Comment: `if (!isset($_POST['s_tselect'])) {
echo "<table><tr><td><b>Mit welchem Trainer willst du losziehen?</b></td></tr><tr><td>";
makeTDropdown();
echo "</td></tr></table>";
}
else {
echo "<table><tr><td><b>Und welches Monster?</b><br></td></tr><tr><td>";
makeMDropdown($_POST['trainerwahl']);
echo "</td></tr></table>";`

Sorry for the early Post, wanted to format and hit enter...

This is in the startseite.php 

The second selection is shown after the first one got submitted. That this overwrites the $_POST array was new to me but I tried to prevent this with my own global array.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I still get `Notice: Undefined index: trainer in..` after submitting the second form.

Comment: Please put codes in questions?

Comment: `global $con; 
 global $wahl;` define these two outside of the function

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to edit this comment anymore. Still new to stackoverflow. I will try to format it in a better way here:  
`if (!isset($_POST['s_tselect'])) { echo "Mit welchem Trainer willst du losziehen?";  
makeTDropdown();}  
else {echo "Und welches Monster?";   makeMDropdown($_POST['trainerwahl']);`  



Sorry I really tried but it seems to stay cluttery. I deleted the html table fuzz to make it more clear.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh they are declared outside of the function - `config.php` holds both variables and also a `require_once('functions.php')`